# Function output appears to be 12, but is returning as a NoneType Object?

Tags: python, object, typeerror, nonetype

I have a function:

```
def check_disk_space(path):
    import os
    """
    check_disk_space() checks the available space of a specified path
    """
    cmdparts = ["echo $(df --output=pcent ", ") | tr -d 'Use% '"]
    check_disk_space_cmd =  cmdparts[0] + path + cmdparts[1]
    print type(os.system(check_disk_space_cmd))
    return os.system(check_disk_space_cmd)
```

if I run it like:

```
if int(check_disk_space('/path/here')) == 12 :
    print "wooot"
```

instead of getting `woot` i get:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

If I print out the `type()` of `os.system(check_disk_space_cmd)` I get `'int'` then the value of `12`.

Any idea what is wrong here? I'm lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Might also want to check out [shutil.disk_usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage)

Comment: if I add `return` to it, it still outputs 12.

Comment: `os.system(check_disk_space_cmd)` returns 12, but *your function* doesn't.

Comment: Python isn't one of those languages where functions automatically return the value of the last expression they evaluate. You have to `return` things explicitly.

Comment: if I do return, i still get the same error..

Comment: See updated function, it still gives me `'int'` and `12`

Comment: We're going to need to see a [mcve] and a complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your function need to return value, so last line of your function should look like

```
return os.system(check_disk_space_cmd)
```